# How to write a very long formula in R?

Tags: r

I have an extremely long formula that I want to write:

```
factors <- paste(paste("housenum_n", c(2:1772), sep = "",
                 collapse = "+"), "+", 
  paste("csozip50Xdate_id", c(2:1549), sep = "", collapse = " + "))

full_form <- paste("sdexantepret60~pre50gnlscr_all2+csoafter50+gnlscr_all2_csoafter50 + hh_eq_mil+numstocks|",
                 factors)

formula <- as.formula(full_form)
```

However, I get the error: Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: Would you be able to do `sdexantepret60~.` where the `.` refers to all other columns

Comment: Also the `as.formula(full_form)` is working fine for me

Comment: Muhammad, if you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question, maybe we'll see why you're getting this error while others don't.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy and paste the code from the question into R it does not give me any errors.

We could make the code a bit more readable by defining Paste and using sprintf.  The number of variables below has been reduced for purposes of illustration.

```
Paste <- function(x, y = "") paste(paste0(x, y), collapse = " + ")

main <- c("pre50gnlscr_all2", "csoafter50", "gnlscr_all2_csoafter50", "hh_eq_mil", 
  "numstocks")

fo_chr <- sprintf("%s ~ %s | %s + %s", 
  "sdexantepret60", 
  Paste(main),
  Paste("housenum_n", 2:5), 
  Paste("csozip50Xdate_id", 2:4)
)
fo <- formula(fo_chr)

fo
```

giving:

```
sdexantepret60 ~ pre50gnlscr_all2 + csoafter50 + gnlscr_all2_csoafter50 + 
    hh_eq_mil + numstocks | housenum_n2 + housenum_n3 + housenum_n4 + 
    housenum_n5 + csozip50Xdate_id2 + csozip50Xdate_id3 + csozip50Xdate_id4
```

Comment: I started a fresh R, ran the garbage collector and everything but I am getting the same error. I set options(expressions = 50000) and ran the code again but this time I got the error: Error: protect(): protection stack overflow

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by running this code from the command line by specifying the option --max-ppsize=50000. However I am not sure how to implement this in Rstudio. Any help would be appreciated. (I tried to run Rstudio with the option --max-ppsize but that didn't work).

Comment: Maybe it's easier just to avoid the problem.  Check if whatever function you are giving the formula to also has a non-formula interface.